# jetty server 9.1 multiple embeded ports and application in same server instance

Tags: java, jetty

I should use one Server object, and need to open multiple ports and multiple application(WAR files).
Ex, one server object,
8080 addition.war
8081 subraction.war
etc.

I'm using Jetty server 9.1.0
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accomplish this, you need:

1. Each [`ServerConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html) should have a unique name declared via `ServerConnector.setName(String)`
2. When you define your [`WebAppContext`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html), declare a set of virtual hosts that take a named virtual host syntax `"@{name}"`, where the `{name}` is the same one you chose for the connector. *(Note: A virtualhost without the "@" sign is a traditional virtualhost based on hostnames)*

Like this ...

```java
package jetty.demo;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class ConnectorSpecificContexts
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server();

        ServerConnector connectorA = new ServerConnector(server);
        connectorA.setPort(8080);
        connectorA.setName("connA"); // connector name A
        ServerConnector connectorB = new ServerConnector(server);
        connectorB.setPort(9090);
        connectorB.setName("connB"); // connector name B

        server.addConnector(connectorA);
        server.addConnector(connectorB);

        // Basic handler collection
        HandlerCollection contexts = new HandlerCollection();
        server.setHandler(contexts);

        // WebApp A
        WebAppContext appA = new WebAppContext();
        appA.setContextPath("/a");
        appA.setWar("./webapps/webapp-a.war");
        appA.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"@connA"}); // connector name A
        contexts.addHandler(appA);

        // WebApp B
        WebAppContext appB = new WebAppContext();
        appB.setContextPath("/b");
        appB.setWar("./webapps/webapp-b.war");
        appB.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"@connB"}); // connector name B
        contexts.addHandler(appB);

        try
        {
            server.start(); // start server thread
            server.join(); // wait for server thread to end
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just great ya. Solved my problem. :)

Comment: One more problem I have, I have atmost 500 application each application may share same port or create new port, when I try with 50 applications its showing exception like Insufficient max threads in ThreadPool: max=200 < needed=295

Comment: I fixed the above problem but getting new problem,
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
for 38th war file, what should I do to solve this? Please help me.

Comment: Ask separate questions.  It is inappropriate to have ongoing conversations in comments section.