# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in embeded jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I am trying to deploy multiple application in a jetty server. Currently I have 50 applications and I'm following the answer from this
[jetty server 9.1 multiple embeded ports and application in same server instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490845/jetty-server-9-1-multiple-embeded-ports-and-application-in-same-server-instance).

I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` at the 38th deployment. How do I solve this?

Comment: increase the perm size not the heap size

Comment: How? 
https://www.google.co.in/#q=permgen+space+eclipse
Tried alll the result from this. I dont knowhow to solve this.

Comment: Where can I increase it? in Code? or in JAVA properties or in Jetty distribution? Everyone simply sugesting to increase permgen but how?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space

Comment: I'm wondering, where can I type this ?
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: When you use java yourProgram  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: I bundled my classes into jar file and tried to run with java -jar jety.jar -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
No changes.

Comment: java -jar jety.jar -XX:MaxPermSize=24m tried this also, no changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any memory control options are part of the JVM that you start for your embedded Jetty application.  That means, in order for you to increase the PermGen that the JVM uses, you'll need to use the command line option `-XX:MaxPermSize` against the JVM when you start your embedded Jetty instance.

Example:

```
$ java -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -cp myserver.jar com.company.EmbeddedMe
```

Since you added the [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) tag, I'll assume you want to know how to configure your "Run Configuration" for this same thing.

In Run > Run Configurations > Arguments Tab > VM Arguments, put `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Comment: Wow.. This worked great. I have to set the size first and then call the jar. Thank you so much.

Comment: plus one for Run Configurations info

Answer (score 1):

Increase the perm and heap size of your jetty instance

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/chghelp/v5m3/topic/com.ibm.rational.change.install.doc/topics/ch_t_ig_change_java_max_heap_jty.html

when you run it via commandline:

```
java -jar -XX:MaxPermSize=512m jety.jar
```

if this doesn't work, increase the size (e.g. 1024m)

Comment: I'm using embedded jetty server. It looks like standalone server.

Comment: how do you run it? via maven?

Comment: No using the link I've given above in my question

Comment: then you need to increase the sizes of you're whole application. how do you run your application? via jar? via commandline? via eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying generates a bunch of `Class` objects which are allocated in the permanent space and never really garbage collected.

To solve this, you might want to increase the size of the permanent space with the JVM option `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` (see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) for more JVM options/descriptions).

Note that starting with Java8, perm space has been [removed](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace). So as an alternative you could also upgrade your JDK to Java8.

Comment: Hendrik, I'm not Re-deploying, I have 50 war files. I'm trying to depoly it in jetty server. At deploy itself, geting this error. I cant deploy after 38th war files.

Comment: The javaw process in task manager reaches 205MB and it got this problem.

Comment: So either start your eclipse with this -XX:MaxPermSize option, or add it to the VM arguments of your run configuration for the embedded jetty server in eclipse.

Comment: In Run configuration I went to (x)=Arguments tab and wrote -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m still no change. Is the variable name wrong?

Comment: -XX... aren't program arguments, but VM-arguments.
Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862391/how-to-pass-the-d-sytem-properties-while-testing-on-eclipse helps you.

Comment: So how should I give?

Comment: Actually, they are VM-arguments, not program arguments. I edited the comment above accordingly.

Comment: Its not really helping :( :(

Comment: Perhaps you want to attach a screenshot of your Eclipse settings and add it to your original question.