# GzipHandler on Jetty uber jar

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I created uber jar with embedded jetty server(I updated to `9.4.20.v20190813`). The fat app includes two parts: the static front-end, and the api backend. The code skeleton copied from [jetty server 9.1 multiple embeded ports and application in same server instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490845/jetty-server-9-1-multiple-embeded-ports-and-application-in-same-server-instance). And I want to add `GzipHandler` on both two web apps.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server();

        ServerConnector connectorA = new ServerConnector(server);
        connectorA.setPort(8080);
        connectorA.setName("connA"); // connector name A (static web app)
        ServerConnector connectorB = new ServerConnector(server);
        connectorB.setPort(9090);
        connectorB.setName("connB"); // connector name B (api app)

        server.addConnector(connectorA);
        server.addConnector(connectorB);

        // Basic handler collection
        HandlerCollection contexts = new HandlerCollection();
        server.setHandler(contexts);

        // WebApp A
        WebAppContext appA = new WebAppContext();
        appA.setContextPath("/a");
        appA.setWar("./webapps/webapp-a.war");
        appA.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"@connA"}); // connector name A
        contexts.addHandler(appA);

        // WebApp B
        WebAppContext appB = new WebAppContext();
        appB.setContextPath("/b");
        appB.setWar("./webapps/webapp-b.war");
        appB.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"@connB"}); // connector name B
        contexts.addHandler(appB);

    GzipHandler gzipHandler = new GzipHandler();
    gzipHandler.setIncludedMethods("POST", "GET");
    gzipHandler.setIncludedMimeTypes("text/html", "text/plain", "text/xml", "text/css", "application/javascript",
                                     "text/javascript", "application/json");
    gzipHandler.setInflateBufferSize(2048);
    gzipHandler.setMinGzipSize(2048);

        contexts.addHandler(gzipHandler);

        try
        {
            server.start(); // start server thread
            server.join(); // wait for server thread to end
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

When I visit `http://localhost:8080`, <s>some resources return `Status Code: 206 Partial Content`.</s> , the server throws exception:

```
17:16:31.447 [qtp60830820-16] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /favicon.ico
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
```

My question: `favicon.ico`'s mime-type is not included in GzipHandler, and why GzipHandler processes it? and `favicon.ico` is in the static resources web app root dir (the same level as `index.html`).

How can I apply the gziphandler correctly? Thanks!

BTW: gzip filter works fine

EDITS:

1. I upgraded jetty version from `9.4.12.v20180830` to `9.4.20.v20190813`
2. I added more settings on GzipHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty 9.1 is EOL (End of Life).

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Your code works, as-is, just upgrade to a supported version of Jetty.

I tested with Jetty 9.4.20.v20190813 and it worked as designed.

The Status Code: `206 Partial Content` is an expected status response code, when the response includes partial range data, which is only produced when the request includes the `Range:` header.

Your code has a handler tree that looks like the following ..

```
Server.setHandler
 \- HandlerCollection
     \- WebAppContext ("/a")
     \- WebAppContext ("/b")
     \- GzipHandler
```

Having the `GzipHandler` at the end will allow the `GzipHandler` to apply to  requests that don't match contexts `"/a"` nor `"/b"`, which is a legitimate configuration, but probably not what you want.

Since you mentioned `favicon.ico`, that's usually a root request, which wouldn't match either `"/a"` nor `"/b"`, so that's what we can only assume is what you want.

But, you didn't actually say that you wanted the `GzipHandler` to apply to the `WebAppContext`, so I'm just going to assume that is what you really wanted to accomplish.

If that's the case, then we need `GzipHandler` to do what it needs BEFORE a `WebAppContext` is entered.

We want a handler tree that looks like this ...

```
Server.setHandler
 \- HandlerList
     \- GzipHandler
     |   \- ContextHandlerCollection
     |       \- WebAppContext ("/a")
     |       \- WebAppContext ("/b")
     \- DefaultHandler
```

Which would be a single `GzipHandler` configured for all contexts.

The rough code would look like this ...

```java
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
server.setHandler(handlers);

WebAppContext appA = new WebAppContext();
appA.setContext("/a");
WebAppContext appB = new WebAppContext();
appB.setContextPath("/b");

ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection(appA, appB);

GzipHandler gzipHandler = new GzipHandler();
gzipHandler.setHandler(contexts);

handlers.addHandler(gzipHandler);
handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
```

But you can also have a unique `GzipHandler` per WebApp.

Looking like this ...

```
Server.setHandler
 \- HandlerList
     \- ContextHandlerCollection
     |   \- WebAppContext ("/a")
     |       \- GzipHandler (instance / config A)
     |   \- WebAppContext ("/b")
     |       \- GzipHandler (instance / config B)
     \- DefaultHandler
```

or like this ...

```
Server.setHandler
 \- HandlerList
     \- GzipHandler (instance / config A)
     |   \- WebAppContext ("/a")
     \- GzipHandler (instance / config B)
     |   \- WebAppContext ("/b")
     \- DefaultHandler
```

Comment: I upgrade the jetty and the problem, please help me to have a look, appreciate your time and thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Joakim Erdfelt. It works great! And you let me know how powerful jetty is!