# In CustomAbstracthandler, Modify Httpfield is not working in jetty server 11 version

Tags: websocket, java-11, embedded-jetty, java-websocket, jetty-10

Getting header `Connection: close, upgrade` from Client, so I am trying to change connection header from `connection: close, upgrade` to `connection: Upgrade`.

I modified  httpfield in CustomAbstractHandler, but not working in Jetty 11 version.

CustomAbstractHandler.Java :

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFields;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CustomAbstractHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAbstractHandler.class);
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpFields.Mutable replacement = HttpFields.build(baseRequest.getHttpFields()).put("Connection", "Upgrade");
        baseRequest.setHttpFields(replacement);
        LOG.info("" + baseRequest.getHttpFields());
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}
```

In Main Class configure Handler in `server.setHandler()`

```java
import java.util.EnumSet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.config.JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer;
import jakarta.servlet.DispatcherType;

public class WebSocketServer {
    private static Server server;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        server = new Server();
        server.setStopTimeout(100);
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setIdleTimeout(1000 * 60 * 60);
        connector.setPort(56667);
        connector.setAcceptedTcpNoDelay(true);
        connector.setAccepting(true);
        connector.join(100);
        connector.setAcceptedReceiveBufferSize(1234567889);
        connector.getConnectedEndPoints();
        server.addConnector(connector);
        ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        contextHandler.setContextPath("/shop");
        FilterHolder filterHolder = contextHandler.addFilter(websocketcreator.class, "/*",
                EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        filterHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);
        contextHandler.getSessionHandler().setMaxInactiveInterval(5);
        server.setHandler(new CustomAbstractHandler());
        contextHandler.addServlet(WebSocketServerServlet.class, "/web-socket/");
        JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(contextHandler, null);
        server.setHandler(contextHandler);
        server.start();
        server.dump(System.err);
        server.join();
    }
```

Anything wrong from the code?

Comment: Need more information.  how are you using this handler? where is it in your handler tree? It could simply be because this handler is not executing at the right time or place within your request handling.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt added config class

Answer (score 0):

Your code is undoing your efforts.

```java
server.setHandler(new CustomAbstractHandler());
...(snip)...
server.setHandler(contextHandler);
```

That replaces `CustomAbstractHandler` with `contextHandler`

The `server.setHandler(Handler)` is a single `Handler`, it looks like you want multiple `Handlers`.

Use a `HandlerList` instead.

```java
// this is a org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.add(new CustomAbstractHandler());
handlers.add(contextHandler);
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

See past answers for more details on Handler trees in Jetty.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217143/775715
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57716374/775715

Comment: I did changes , but not working

`HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList(new CustomAbstractHandler(),contextHandler);
  
  server.setHandler(handlers);`

Comment: Do you want your Request field changes in `CustomAbstractHandler` to propagate into the `contextHandler`?  If so, remove the `baseRequest.setHandled(true);` (this is mentioned in the past answers btw)

Comment: how can change incoming header value in  entry of Request in Request class or HttpChannel Class